# How to check if a value is in multiple dimensions of an array

Tags: excel, vba

I need a way to check if there is the same value in multiple dimensions of the array. For an example, if we had:

```
Array(0, 0) = 1   Array(1, 0) = 5
Array(0, 1) = 2   Array(1, 1) = 2
Array(0, 2) = 3   Array(1, 2) = 4
```

then the function would return the number 2, as it was in the array for both dimensions.

I've tried thinking if looping through the array multiple times would work, perhaps assigning the variable a number for each time it showed up and checking against the number of dimensions in the array, but am not sure on how to get it to work or if there is another method possible.

Comment: Loop through array, and save each unique number in a `Dictionary`. If you get a `Dict.Exists` for a certain value, you know it already exists in the array.